# Box rigging with empty groups does not work

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to create an animation of folding a box. I have a model of unfolded box and armature. But when set parent with empty groups, there are vertex groups for only two bones of twelve. There are no doubles on model. Model is in one mesh.
When I make my own vertex groups for every bone (with bone names), it does not work too.
What am I doing wrong?
[image: unfolded box and armature]

Comment: Sounds like you got this working, but in future, check for "deform" property on bones.  Groups won't be made for non-deforming bones.

Answer (score 0):

Try using automatic weights instead. That will create the groups for you.

Comment: Automatic weights made smooth edges when bend a bone and I need sharp folds. Thats why I used Empty groups. I just solved my problem. I created new armature and it is working properly now :)

Comment: @Katka Can we see?